# php filter search results

Tags: php, mysql, search, filtering

hello I developped a search form with php,which is working perfectly,but I would like to filter for example alphabetically,so I defined some  anchors in my html document
           A| B | ....

In my php document,I added:

```
        $search=$_POST['query']//query is the name of input in a form,on the same html doc
        $letter=$_GET['by'];
```

from my sql query,

```
        $sql=SELECT Title FROM table where Title LIKE %search%;
```

I added :

```
          if(isset($letter)){
             $sql .="AND Name LIKE '$letter' ";
           }
```

My problem is that when I click for example on the link "A" it  always display all entry corresponding of all titles having names beginning of letter"A".(my Table has 2 columns,Title and Name) So I would like when I do a search to filter the results(getting when I click on "A" titles for which names begin by "A" and only those returned on the result of the search)

Comment: You can't submit a form and click a link at the same time

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have a space before the AND; but you need to wildcard the LIKE

```
$sql .=" AND Name LIKE '$letter%' ";
```